# Marking duplicate values in new column

Tags: sql, excel, count, duplicates

So I'm in need of some help on a query that will mark duplicates in a specific column.

essentially I have 2 columns like this:

```
cust_id    Order_id
  001        001
  001        002
  001        003
  002        001
  003        001
  003        002
```

I want to make a new column in my Q that marks a '1' for unique and '0' for duplicates of only the cust_id column.  My thought is to use the min or < function on the order_id column in order to determine which cust_id was entered first to mark as '1'

So far this is what I have come up with which is obviously not right:

```
SELECT
A.cust_id,
B.order_id,
CASE
WHEN COUNT(A.cust_id) > 1 THEN 0
WHEN COUNT(A.cust_id) = 1 THEN 1
END AS 'TESTING'

FROM CUST A INNER JOIN ORDER B
ON B.cust_id = A.cust_id

GROUP BY B.order_id, A.cust_id
```

This runs but only marks everything with a '1'.  I know that it's because it's doing exactly what I asked it to do, and that it is actually looking at the value of the cust_id and why ALL are > 1 and returning all '1's.

How do I re-write this to mark the first instance of cust_id with a '1' and the rest (or duplicate cust_id's as '0'

the purpose is so I can summarize the '1's in excel and do calculations from there for a pivot chart.

Thanks in advance for the help!!!!!  this site has saved my life more than once!

EDIT:

Using MS SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Why is this tagged Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cust_id    Order_id     Unique
  001        001          1
  001        002          0 
  001        003          0
  002        001          1
  003        001          1
  003        002          0
```

Is the above result set what you are looking for? Below is an example based on the AdventureWorks database. The reason you are getting all 1's above is due to the grouping over cust and order. You want to group over just Cust.

```
use AdventureWorks2008R2

;with CustSales as

(

select 

    C.CustomerID,

    H.SalesOrderID, 

    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by C.CustomerID order by SalesOrderID)  as s 

from Sales.Customer C 

join Sales.SalesOrderheader H on 

C.CustomerID = H.CustomerID 

)

select 

    CustomerID,

    SalesOrderID,

    case when s = 1 then 1 else 0 end as [Unique]

from CustSales
```

Comment: Thanks again, I was able to nest this into my Q fairly easily and now I have a very functional table in excel that I can use to power all my pivot tables and thus only needing one slicer to power all tables.  ie: instead of each chart having employee slicer now one slicer controls all charts where applicable.

Comment: I have to admit that I do not quite understand what is going on with the row_number... line so I guess I have some more studying to do.  I get that I gave the original Q an alias and then worked from there.  I'm a newb and that is a first for me.  I would just do a package but was told needs to be done in one query.

Comment: Row_Number() generates a series of numbers whose values depend on columns that are selected. So for each block of customerID's (partition) an ordered series of numbers is generated that matches the order of "order by SalesOrderID. Look up Windowing functions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, CASE s.num WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END uniq
  FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN (SELECT cust_id, COUNT(*) num FROM Table1 GROUP BY cust_id) s
      ON s.cust_id = t1.cust_id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abb97/3)

Comment: This doesn't incorporate the join with the Order table and therefore the order_id.  The cust_id is unique with no dupes on it's own. it's only when I put the orders with the customers that I get duplicates on the customers.

Comment: Using MS SQL 2008 r2, not sure if it makes a difference but the SQLFiddle didn't work for it